# Grouped column diff, based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Here is my dataframe:

```
metric_name ts count
m_1         1  10
m_2         1  20
m_1         2  12
m_2         2  19
```

I would like to get diff of `count` value for each metric_name

```
m_1         1    0  # start for m_1
m_2         1    0  # start for m_2
m_1         2    2  # 12 - 10
m_2         2   -1  # 19 - 20
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) each group value with `np.diff` function (to calculate the *n*-th discrete difference):

```
df.groupby('metric_name')['count'].transform('diff').fillna(0)
```

---

```
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    2.0
3   -1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Then of course, if you're no `groupby` adept, there's always this method:
*(Not at all suggesting that `groupby` is bad here; one just might be more at ease with `.loc` wet work when it suffices.)*

```py
for m in df['metric_name'].unique():
    df.loc[df['metric_name']==m, 'diff'] = df.loc[df['metric_name']==m, 'count'].diff().fillna(0)

  metric_name  ts  count  diff
0         m_1   1     10   0.0
1         m_2   1     20   0.0
2         m_1   2     12   2.0
3         m_2   2     19  -1.0
```